# Why shows my custom colored snackbar white fields at its the bottom and top

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I have colored my snackbar. But this snackbar shows a small white stripe at the bottom and anotherone at the top.
You can see it inside the two red frames (which are not part of my app - just shown here for demonstration). The darker I choose the background, the better you can see these stripes.
The stripes are coming from the MainActivity Background. When I change this background color, the color of these stripes are also changing there color.
I played around with some padding on the two text fields, but didn't find a solution to loose these stripes.

How can I get rid of this white stripe?

```
View contextView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
    .make(contextView, "HELLO", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .setDuration(3500)
    .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.korall));

// Change the Snackbar default text color
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
TextView tv = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.nightPrimaryLight));

tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
tv.setPadding(24,52,0,52);

TextView tva = snackbarView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_action);
tva.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.korall));

tva.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
tva.setPadding(0,34,24,24);

tva.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
tv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));

snackbar.show();;
```

[image]

Comment: try to remove the padding

Comment: I have, but the behavior remains the same.

Comment: Are you using the material components library or the design library?

Comment: I use the AppCompat Library